# Active Record and PostGIS ST_BUFFER: LinearRing failed ring test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, geometry, postgis

An app I'm working on has a `regions` table containing a geometry column called `polygon`. The app is using PostGIS via the `activerecord-postgis-adapter` gem. Active Record migrations involving geometry columns result in a schema that shows:

`t.geometry "polygon", limit: {:srid=>0, :type=>"geometry"}`

Users can store circles, rectangles, and polygons via a Leaflet.js map in the front end. When a circle is created, the browser request includes the center and radius (in meters).

To create a circle, the app stores the center and radius along with a polygon. To save the polygon, the `Region` model uses the following method:

```
def uncached_circle(coordinates, radius)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
    SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('#{uncached_point(coordinates.first)}')::geography, #{radius}, 'quad_segs=8')::geometry AS circle;
  ")[0]["circle"]
end
```

I'm having a few problems, the most pressing of which is that certain circles fail with a `LinearRing failed ring test` error. For example, these request parameters:

`{"name"=>"New Orleans, LA", "coordinates"=>[{"lat"=>29.9510658, "lng"=>-90.0715323}], "radius"=>25000, "shape"=>"circle", "format"=>:json, "region"=>{"name"=>"New Orleans, LA", "shape"=>"circle"}}`

...produce this query from the aforementioned method:

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(29.9510658 -90.0715323)')::geography, 25000, 'quad_segs=8')::geometry AS circle;
```

...which fails with the LinearRing error. Another circle centered in Boston (for example) passes.

I rely on the polygon representation of the circle to conduct intersection tests with other circles.

I'm not experienced with PostGIS and am unable to get around this issue after a lot of research and a variety of attempts. The closest I can get is to wrap the circle creation queries in `ST_MakeValid`, which I view as a code smell.

Can anyone diagnose what I've done wrong? Happy to provide more detail as needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're switching the order of the coordinate pairs. It should be `lon,lat` instead of `lat,lon`.

So, try your query using `POINT(-90.0715323 29.9510658)` and **not** `POINT(29.9510658 -90.0715323)`:

```
SELECT 
  ST_Buffer('POINT(-90.0715323 29.9510658)'::geography, 
            25000, 
            'quad_segs=8')::geometry AS circle;
```

[image]

Further reading: [`WGS84`](https://epsg.io/4326) (EPSG:4326)

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the problem. To get everything working in the front end I also had to reverse the coordinates being sent back to the browser. Leaflet expects lat/lng (vs postgis expecting lng/lat).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why having the coordinates reversed would cause ST_BUFFER to output an ellipse?

Comment: @Ephs05msm the problem was that your latitude value was out of range, which has a minimum value of -90 and yours was 90.07. So, in a sense your point was placed "nowhere".

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for explaining. There were cases where the buffer would be valid even though the center point coordinates were reversed. When that happened, I was seeing an ellipse. Thanks again for the help.